# MySQL error, missing sock, can still connect with everything except command line

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect to MySQL through the command line (Ubuntu 14.04)

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Seems that the file `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` is missing. MySQL is still running

```
% sudo service mysql status                                                    
mysql start/running, process 42703
```

and I am able to connect with MySQLdb and sqlalchemy via Python and through MySQL Workbench and MySQL Pro. I was running a Python script and got the following error

> (1053, 'Server shutdown in progress')

I restarted the script and everything ran like usual but since this point I have been unable to connect via command line. Not sure what happened or why the sock would disappear. I also ran

```
sudo find / -type s
```

and nothing related to MySQL is found.

**UPDATE**: Seems that someone uncommented bind-address = 127.0.0.1 (inside /etc/mysql/my.cnf), restarted the server, realized this was a mistake, put it back, and restarted. Would this remove the sock file?

Comment: They're probably connecting via TCP then and not the socket.

Comment: Try connecting via tcp. `mysql -u $user -p --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3306`

Comment: I'm able to connect that way.

Comment: So what's your actual question?

Comment: Why all of the sudden do I have to type `mysql -u $user -p --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3306` when I used to be able to type `mysql`? Why am I getting the errors I posted? Why did the .sock file disappear?

Comment: Well the answer to the first is _because_ your socket file has been removed. Why has it been removed? We can't really tell you. Check more of your logs. Did something crash? Did said person who restarted the server mess something else up? We don't know.

Comment: Cool, thanks, can you move that to an actual answer instead of a comment so I can accept it as "correct"?

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be that multiple mysql processes are running. Try stopping mysql and mysqld processes followed by restarting mysql:

```
sudo pkill mysql
sudo pkill mysqld
sudo service mysql restart
```

now you should be able to log into mysql normally

```
mysql -u root -p
```

if it still doesn't work, and you're mysql database is local, try changing the bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to localhost before attempting to kill the processes like I showed you above.

Open up the configuration file:

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

look for the line containg **bind-address** and change the line to

```
bind-address            = localhost
```

save the file and exit

now kill the processes and restart mysql ( first 3 steps in the beginning of this comment).